# Cannot log into TFS on the server that it is installed, but can log in from local machine(s)?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Today I installed TFS 2013 Express on our staging server.  From our local machines we can connect to TFS in Visual Studio as well as the web admin panel.  From my machine I added all the code files and performed a check in.  My associate was able to connect to the server and get latest.  We both were able to check out files, make small changes, check in, and then get latest to see each others edits.  Everything seems to be working correctly.

If I RDC/RDP into the staging server and try to add the server to Visual Studio 2013 Express it prompts me for a username and password. After 3 tries of entering my valid username and password, it throws an error.

[image]

I am positive I am entering the username and password correctly.If I access web admin panel from the server as I am RDP'ed in, it is doing the same thing, acting like its rejecting the username and password... the same usernames and passwords that work just fine on our local machines.

I am at a loss as to how to even begin troubleshooting this.

Comment: Are you using the servername or localhost?

Comment: I've tried both tfs.ourdomain.com/tfs (which is what we are using on our local boxes) and the servername.

Comment: like http://localhost:8080/tfs?  That errors immediately with the TF31002: Unable to connect error

Comment: Is that server domain joined?

Comment: here is something that is really strange.  If I am logged into the server via RDC as MyAdminName, and then try to log into the web admin panel from my local box as MyAdminName, it fails. If I log in to the web admin panel from my local box as TheOtherAdminName, it will work